# How to disable --footer-html on first 3 pages wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: java, wkhtmltopdf

I'm generating pdf with wkhtmltopdf. There is a problem, that I cannot disable --footer-html on first THREE pages.

Below is java code for generating pdf:

```
        pdf.addPageFromString(parseThymeleafTemplate());
        pdf.addParam(new Param("--page-size", "A4", "-B", "35mm", "-L", "0", "-R", "0", "-T", "0"));
        pdf.addParam(new Param("--footer-html", "/Users/kuanysh/IdeaProjects/pdf-report-sender/src/main/resources/templates/footer.html"));
```

And my footer.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script>
        function subst() {
            var vars = {};
            var x = document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
            for (var i in x) {
                var z = x[i].split('=', 2);
                vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);
            }
            var x = ['frompage', 'topage', 'page', 'webpage', 'section', 'subsection', 'subsubsection'];
            for (var i in x) {
                var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);
                for (var j = 0; j < y.length; ++j) y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];

                if (vars['page'] === 1) { // If page is 1, set FakeHeaders display to none
                    document.getElementById("stopFooter").style.display = 'none';
                }
if (vars['page'] === 2) { // If page is 1, set FakeHeaders display to none
                    document.getElementById("stopFooter").style.display = 'none';
                }
if (vars['page'] === 3) { // If page is 1, set FakeHeaders display to none
                    document.getElementById("stopFooter").style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div onload="subst()">
        <footer class="footer" id="stopFooter">
        <p>I am footer</p>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <p>Hello</p>
        </footer>
    </div></body>

</html>
```

And it's not working. Does wkhtmltodpf library give us some functions for that?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `onload="subst()"` from the `div`.

Then change your function into a self invoking function by changing its opening and closing lines:

`function subst() {` becomes `(function () {`
and the last (closing) `}` becomes `})();`

Don't forget to remove the script from the `head`. Place it into the `body` below your `div`. Otherwise the script will run before the HTML get's loaded without having any effect.

Comment: Thank you! But there is anyway free space. Is it possible to remove it?

Comment: The remaining free space is a known probem unfortunately. wkhtmltopdf calculates the necessary space and loads the footer before we actually hide it with the javascript.

Comment: pdf.addParam(new Param("--page-size", "A4", "-B", "35mm", "-L", "0", "-R", "0", "-T", "0")); - because of I'm adding 35mm to bottom there is a free space. Without it there will be no footer in any page